# Why the need to say "sur elle que" instead of "sur laquelle"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions, pronoms-relatifs

> 〇 L'École de l'étoile, c'est **sur elle que** j'en sais le moins.
>
> × L'École de l'étoile, c'est **sur laquelle** j'en sais le moins.

Given the preposition "sur", I'm tempted to use "sur laquelle" myself, but apparently "sur elle que" is the phrase to go for here. I wonder why?

Incidentally, the same goes for the following example:

> 〇 Et même mon arrière-grand-tante. En fait, c'est **par elle que** tout a commencé.
>
> × Et même mon arrière-grand-tante. En fait, c'est **par laquelle** tout a commencé.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans la phrase :

> L'École de l'étoile, c'est sur elle que j'en sais le moins.

*elle* est un **pronom personnel** complément de *sais*.

*Laquelle* est un **pronom relatif**, l'emploi du pronom relatif est différent de celui du pronom personnel. Pour pouvoir l'utiliser il faut que le nom qu'il représente soit présent **juste avant le pronom relatif** (ce mot s'appelle l'antécédent en grammaire).

«  L'École de l'étoile, » ne peut pas servir d'antécédent au pronom relatif parce qu'il est séparé du pronom relatif par le verbe.  On va donc introduire un pronom qui va représenter *L'École de l'étoile* juste avant *sur laquelle*, ici on peut utiliser le pronom personnel *elle* ou le pronom démonstratif *celle*.

> L'École de l'étoile, c'est celle sur laquelle j'en sais le moins.
>   L'École de l'étoile, c'est elle sur laquelle j'en sais le moins.
>   L'École de l'étoile est celle sur laquelle j'en sais le moins.

De même avec :

> Et même mon arrière-grand-tante. En fait, c'est par elle que tout a commencé.
>
> Et même mon arrière-grand-tante. En fait, c'est **celle** par laquelle tout a commencé.
>
> Et même mon arrière-grand-tante. En fait, c'est **elle** par laquelle tout a commencé.
>
> Mon frère, c'est celui par lequel tout a commencé.
>
> Mon frère, c'est lui par lequel tout a commencé.

---

In the sentence:

> L'École de l'étoile, c'est sur elle que j'en sais le moins.

*elle* is a personal pronoun.

*Laquelle* is a relative pronoun and you need to have the noun to which it refers just before it (and cannot separate the two by a verb). Therefore you need to have *elle* if you want to use the relative pronoun *laquelle*. You could use the demonstrative pronoun  *celle* as well (in fact in this precise sentence *celle* would sound better).

> L'École de l'étoile, c'est celle sur laquelle j'en sais le moins.